# Angular ui.bootstrap accordion and bootstrap3

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm well aware that `ui.bootstrap` is not yet fully ported on bootstrap 3, but I have built most of my app using it, and I can't simply go back to 2.3 just for this component.

That said, I'm evaluating my possibilities.

What I have tried so far:

1. **Revert to Bootstrap 2.3**
   Broke all my stylings... no way
2. **Stick to BS3 and grab the accordion from https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/tree/bootstrap3**
   I've either tried to include the code below the ui.bootstrap_0.7 lib, replaced the accordion code in ui.bootstrap 0.7 code and removed it and placed it in another file entirely. None of this have worked
3. **Stick to BS3 and tried to steal the accordion styles from BS2.3**
   This way I've managed to add a style to it, but the accordion behavior simply wasn't working

In every single try, no error is shown on the console...

I'm wandering in the dark, with no clue on how to include the accordion in my code without re-implementing it anew.
Any help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Why not get the custom build of the bootstrap3 branch till it is officially supported and released? All the components (but progress) are working in the mentioned branch.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Actually, that is what I've tried in point 2, failing hard.  
If there's a way to create a custom build for the bs3 branch, I failed to notice it.  
I suppose I could create a bs2 custom build and then overwrite all the accordion-related parts with the one in the bs3 branch... Is this what you're suggesting?

Comment: you can create a custom build from Grunt as described here: https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap#build. Or simply remove unneeded directives from the default build.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource Great, I got it working.  Since my main machine is KO, I was unable to use Grunt on the windows (sigh) machine I'm working atm.
I've built a _Frankestein_, overriding the `collapse`, `transition` and `accordion` modules, and got it working, thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap 3 uses panels instead of the accordion class.  The template should change for that.  Not to change ui-bootstrap, I overwrote the module that has the template for the accordion.  This module should be added to your js class (and should load after ui-bootstrap):

```
angular.module("template/accordion/accordion-group.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/accordion/accordion-group.html",
    "<div class=\"panel panel-default\">\n" +
    "  <div class=\"panel-heading\" >\n" +
    "    <h4 class=\"panel-title\"><a data-toggle=\"collapse\" ng-click=\"isOpen = !isOpen\" accordion-transclude=\"heading\">{{heading}}</a></h4>\n" +
    "  </div>\n" +
    "  <div class=\"panel-collapse\" ng-hide=\"!isOpen\">\n" +
    "    <div class=\"panel-body\" ng-transclude></div>  </div>\n" +
    "</div>");
}]);

angular.module("template/accordion/accordion.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/accordion/accordion.html",
    "<div class=\"panel-group\" ng-transclude></div>");
}]);
```

Find this sample in [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/e7L6ewThMdKVaVyrr3Po?p=preview)

Comment: Yeah, I solved it in much the same way. Only I have overwritten the logic too... not sure if it was needed though.

Answer (score 1):

you have to **reference only the "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" file**

that was my case at least, i was referencing both in this order:

```
ui-bootstrap-tpls.js
ui-bootstrap.js
```

and the "ui-bootstrap" was overriding the templates

Answer (score 0):

mlim1972 answers work well, however i used angular $provide decorator to do that(in coffeescript):

```
module.config( ["$provide", ($provide) ->
  $provide.decorator 'accordionDirective', ["$delegate", ($delegate) ->
  $delegate[0].templateUrl = "path/to/modified/accordion-group.html"
  $delegate
]
```